# How to pass the button value from view to controller in order to filter data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an application where I need to pass the button value from view to controller to filter the DB.

Here I need to display years from  2009 to 2018/current year as button for that I used action link. I am not sure how to pass the year which I am getting in for loop to my controller to get only the clicked year results.

View :

```
var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (var i = year; i > 2009; i--)
{
    var j = @i - 1;
            <div class="col-md-1 ">
                @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "MyCases/" + i)
            </div>                
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult MyCases(int i)
{
    var cases = _db.case.Where(p => p.date.Value.Year == i)
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.date).ToList();
    return View(cases);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the year as the route values parameter of the ActionLink overload you are using. Pass an anonymous object with name same as your action method parameter name(`i`).

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "MyCases", new { i = i })
```

The `ActionLink`helper will build the correct markup for an anchor tag where your href attribute value will be like `MyCases?i=2018` where `2018` is a sample value of `i`

You can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505040(v=vs.118)#linkextensionsactionlink-method-htmlhelperstringstringstringobjectobject) to explicitly specify the controller name

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "MyCases","Home", new { i = i }, null)
```